# Does using a Dell-Ubuntu image provide better hardware support for the XPS 13?

Tags: drivers, dell, xps

I found [this link](http://www.dell.com/support/Article/us/en/19/SLN265886/EN) with directions to build a Dell-Ubuntu image, complete with recovery partition. Does the Dell-Ubuntu image offer improved hardware support, patches from Dell, etc or is a user better off to use the latest Ubuntu and kernel?